# How to reload an application on running tomcat with Spring MVC without changing or adding the config xml files?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I have been trying to make a new URL to reload an running application on TOMCAT, but I haven't found a good way so far.

I am using Spring MVC framework and I tried to make a ContextRefreshedEvent class, but It didn't work.
I also tried to do with the **org.apache.catalina.valves.ValveBase** like this

```
public void invoke(Request request, Response response) throws IOException, ServletException {
    Container container = getContainer();
    ((Context) container).reload();
}
```

I want to expect that the running an application on tomcat reload some new jar files.

Could you please help or sample code?

Comment: You want to reload your application because you can't stop sessions ?

Comment: I have been developing the abilists tool (www.abilists.com) with Plugin sytem, I don't want user have to set the configuration in Tomcat after installing the Abilists.
If there is a good way, I want to introduce the way to the Abilists tool.